# How to set the video parameter with the flash-torch-light on?

Tags: android

I got the code from internet in how to turn the torch light on in android. But that code is not working for me. Code as below:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_flash_light);



    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

    if (! pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Your phone does not have flash light support.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }

    camera = Camera.open(); 
    cParameters = camera.getParameters();



    cParameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
camera.setParameters(cParameters);

}
```

I am using LG optimus 3D, 2.2 version. I discover that my phone's camera will only emit torch light when it is in video mode (normal camera mode give flashlight only). I am searching how to add the video mode parameter into the camera.setParameters(), but there is no such parameter. So, how am I going to do that?

I have run the code below to confirm that my phone is supporting torch mode:

```
List<String> abc = cParameters.getSupportedFlashModes();

        for (String a : abc){
            Log.d("mode: ", a);
        }
```

Comment: I have tried FLASH_MODE_ON also does not work.

Comment: I have called camera.startPreview after that , also does not work.